# Update TFS Build Quality when unit tests pass

Tags: tfs

Im trying to update the build quality of a build when the unit tests pass.. I figured how to update the quality of the build using a statement like this...

```
<Target Name="AfterEndToEndIteration">
<SetBuildProperties
  TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)"
  BuildUri="$(BuildUri)"
  Quality="Unit Test Passed" />
```

But i cant seem to isolate the Target when the unit tests SUCCESSFULLY pass.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the TestStatus property to make the target conditional as per Aaron Hallberg's blog post:
http://blogs.msdn.com/aaronhallberg/archive/2008/05/12/orcas-sp1-tfs-build-changes-part-2.aspx

```
<Target Name="AfterEndToEndIteration" Condition="'$(TestStatus)'=='Succeeded'">
  ...
</Target>
```